# Difference between using and not using new pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, stack, new-operator

Please refer the code given here:

This code is a part of stack implementation in C++:

**Code 1:**

```
void Stack::pop()
{
    if (top != 0) {
        node* temp = top;
        top = top -> link;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

**Code 2:**

```
void Stack::pop()
{
    if (top != 0) {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp = top;
        top = top -> link;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

In first example, I didn't use **new**, while I did use it in second one. On running, both give same output with the complete program, which can be found below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    string name;
    node* link;
};

class Stack
{
    node* top;
public:
    Stack();
    void push(string s);
    void pop();
    void display();
    ~Stack(){}
};

Stack::Stack() {
    top = 0;
}

void Stack::push(string s)
{
    node* temp = new node;
    temp -> name = s;
    temp -> link = top;
    top = temp;
}

void Stack::pop() // Function in question
{
    if (top != 0) {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp = top;
        top = top -> link;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void Stack::display()
{
    node* temp = new node;
    temp = top;
    while (temp != 0)
    {
        cout << temp -> name << "\n";
        temp = temp -> link;
    }
}

int main() {
    Stack s;
    s.push("Ra");
    s.push("Sa");
    s.push("Ga");
    s.pop();
    s.display();
}
```

What is the **difference** in using and not using **new** pointer here?

Also does the memory automatically free itself or do I have to do it in destructor? If so, how to do it?

Comment: @Abhineet Sorry I didn't find it useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's memory leak in the 2nd code snippet, even though it looks working well. `new node` is meaningless for `node* temp = new node;`, because `temp` is assigned to `top` at once. Then the original memory address created by `new node` is lost and couldn't be `delete`d again.

> Also does the memory automatically free itself or do I have to do it in destructor?

Each object `new`ed has to be `delete`d by yourself. Consider about [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers), they will manage such things for you.

Comment: Why can't it be deleted again? What happened?

Comment: @samjoe Because it's lost.

Comment: Hey is it that I gave it another location after declaring it? That is the original location that was allocated got lost, and I gave it new address?

Comment: @samjoe Yes. The original address is lost when you assign it to a new one.

Answer (score 3):

In these lines:

```
    node* temp = new node;
    temp = top;
```

you allocate new node, store it in `temp` variable and ton the next variable store in the same variable another pointer. So that new node is lost and newer used. `node* temp = new node;` has no effect other than leaking memory.

> Also does the memory automatically free itself or do I have to do it
>   in destructor?

No. Memory is not freed automatically. And you nearly never actually call object destructor manually.

> If so, how to do it?

The old way is to use `delete`. But im modern C++ you should not use naked owning pointers and really should consider using `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: I think it is better to use std::shared_ptr for the implementation becomes easier when assigning and copying shared_ptrs

Comment: With `unique_ptr` you always know who owns the object. That brings order to programs and order is good for readability and stability. With `shared_ptr` you can make accidentally make loops and make your code more complex. `shared_ptr` are not bad, but they should not be used everywhere. Beside that `unique_ptr` is a more lightweight construction.

Comment: I agree. But how will you traverse the linked list if its links are unique_ptrs?

Comment: The list owns stored object so it holds `unique-ptr`'s. Function that traverses the list does not own stored objects, it does not care about their lifetime and does not manage it, so it gets plain pointers.

Comment: Cool that makes sense.

Comment: If you have time, do comment on my implemention of the stack using the unique_ptrs.. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2):

While using new/allocating the memory, you are causing a memory leak.

```
node* temp = new node;
temp = top; //temp is now pointing to a new memory location.
            //Thus the memory allocated by in the previous code line gets leaked
```

Code1 is the correct way to do it. Code 2 causes memory leak.

You have to delete the memory that you allocate using the delete operator in the destructor.

```
Stack::~Stack()
{
    while(NULL != top)
    {
        node* temp = top;
        top = top->link;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

A smart pointer Solution. You will need c++11 compiler for the following code to compile/work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    string name;
    std::unique_ptr<node> link;
};    
typedef std::unique_ptr<node> node_ptr;

class Stack
{
    node_ptr top;
public:
    Stack();
    void push(string s);
    void pop();
    void display();
    ~Stack(){}
};

Stack::Stack() {
}

void Stack::push(string s)
{
    auto temp = std::make_unique<node>();
    temp -> name = s;
    temp -> link = top;
    top = temp;
}

void Stack::pop()
{
    if (top != null) {
        top = top -> link;
    }
}

void Stack::display() const
{
    node* temp = top.get();
    while (temp != 0)
    {
        cout << temp -> name << "\n";
        temp = (temp -> link).get();
    }
}

int main() {
    Stack s;
    s.push("Ra");
    s.push("Sa");
    s.push("Ga");
    s.pop();
    s.display();
}
```